# WebClient Form Data with french special characters are not transmitted correctly

Tags: webclient, htmlunit

I am using HtmlUnit 2.13 to send data using a form, everything works fine, the problem is with french characters like (é, è, â, ê, °n, etc ...) are not transmitted correctly :

example : a have a text input for address information : lets say "Cité BLABLABLA n° 123", only "Cit" is transferred but everything after the character "é" (and the other characters mentionned before) is not transmitted.

Comment: Please, explain in detail what you mean by *is not transmitted*

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you declare `<meta charset="UTF-8">` inside the head tag and you should be okay.

Comment: where to put this i my java code ? i get the page via webClient.getPage(url), i fill the form, then i send it via button.click();

Comment: i used this page.getWebClient().addRequestHeader("charset", "UTF-8"); but still the same problem.

Comment: try page.getWebClient().addRequestHeader("Content-Type","text/html; charset=utf-8");